# Kafka Producer Send String Not Working

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I am trying to make a kafka producer that sends a string "This program is running" to a kafka topic. I am not sure why it is not working. Below is the following code. I am not Cloudera distribution.

```
package kafka_test;

import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;

public class DataMovement {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String kafkaTopic = args[0];

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "server:9092");
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());

        KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(props);
        ProducerRecord<String, String> producerRecord = new ProducerRecord<String, String>(kafkaTopic, null, "This program is running.");

        producer.send(producerRecord);
        producer.close();

    }
}
```

I don't get an error message but a timeout:

It also outputs lots of information about the Kafka, ssl, passowrd, client.id etc.

16/10/31 10:25:46 INFO utils.AppInfoParser: Kafka version : 0.9.0.1
16/10/31 10:25:46 INFO utils.AppInfoParser: Kafka commitId : commitid
16/10/31 10:26:46 INFO producer.KafkaProducer: Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 9223372036854775807 ms.

Comment: Are you getting any exception? also before closing the producer, you can wait for some time using Thread.sleep(2000), once the producer is closed, kafka will not send the message to topic.

Comment: Also, if you are not setting any message key, you can use ProducerRecord with two arguments, topic name and message.

Comment: It is a time out error. I made an edit. okay let me try changing the key. Let me try sleep.

Comment: Make sure  zookeeper and Kafka broker is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works fine. Problem was the server:9092 should be the address of the designated broker of the Kafka cluster (I had it targeted on the active broker, they are different).

Comment: Can you clarify? Any active worker should work as bootstrap server - it will simply redirect the client (using MetadataResponse) to talk to a different server if needed.

Comment: We had two brokers, each having its own node. For some reason, when directing to one of them the message does not populate (we can call this broker_node_2 as example). When we directed the send data to broker_node_1 it ended up working. Not sure the reason. Might be the way the cluster was set up.

Comment: @Defcon - I am literally stuck over here, I have commented the listeners property #listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092 and using props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092"); both for creating a topic and producer api. Topic is getting created but Producer api is not pushing any messages even if commit-id is printed in logs.